# Why does my motherboard manufacturer recommend that I use the A2/B2 memory channels before A1/B1?

Tags: memory, motherboard

My motherboard has 4 memory slots, divided into two channels. In my motherboard's manual it is recommended that you use slots A2 and B2 before A1 and B1, as you can see in the image below. But why is this recommended? Running two RAM modules in A1 and B1 seems to work fine, so why is it recommended to use A2 and B2 first?

EDIT: The motherboard uses an Intel Z97 Express chipset.
[image]

Comment: Contact the manufacture and ask.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably because those two slots are used for dual channel operation.

[Wikipedia page about multi-channel memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture)

Comment: As are, in all likelyhood, the other two slots.

Comment: The dual-channel slots are usually the pair further from the CPU socket.

Comment: All boards I have used could use four DIMMs in two dual channel sets. (or two sets of three in triple channel for the X58 board). As such I never encountered a set where you have 4 sockets and only two are capable of dual channel. (You could mess up and use something as A1/A2 above, loosing dual channel completely, but I see no good reason why A1/B1 and A2/B2 would not offer this. Which makes it an interesting question from the OP.

Comment: I just assumed you would lose dual channel if you use the "wrong" slots.